# Phabricator doesnt map user to svn commiter

Tags: phabricator

I have a problem that phabricator doesnt map user to svn commit in Diffusion, if the commits are commited before the user is created in phabricator. So the user will not receipt any notification related to that commit. Is there a way to map those commits to the user too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can request a reparse of the commits from the command line.

```
bin/repository reparse --all REPO --message
```

The reparsing will happen in background, so don't expect instant results after the command is run.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you explain more about the command like what does it actually do? Will it affect any of the existing repo in diffusion like comment, audit related to it?

Comment: The --message option tells reparse to reparse commit messages and authors.  Herald rules will not be retriggered, and the actual change will not be reparsed so any audit comments should remain attached to the change. You can read more here: https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/repository_imports/